# "Always use this program" is greyed out for certain files

Tags: windows, file-association

Here is the context :

The problem started when some file icons didn't diplayed. So I search the web and most answers, if not all, were related to the icon cache database. I tried most solutions and they didn't work. Even the icon cache database is rebuilded each time.

- I notice this problem was for all accounts. So it was not related to my account.
- This problem is for certain applications like all Office apps, Adobe Acrobat, etc. All major softwares.

I tried to change an icon associated to a filetype manually and this is when I noticed that I could not change the default program for the tested filetype. This is true for all filetypes where the icons were missing.

Also when launching some files, the app starts and popups an error message, but only on some files.

**TL;DR;**

- Missing icons
- "Always use this program greyed out" for what seem "officially" registered apps and for all accounts

Some might find this question related to [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/153465/always-use-this-program-to-open-these-files-is-grayed-out-why), but there are not the same.

So this is driving me nut!

**Update 1**

This seems to affect the softwares that are installed for all users, not the one installed for the current user.
Apps such as Chrome is not affected neither is Firefox, because I chose to install them in my session only.

Comment: Why are they different questions?

Comment: Because the other question was about a single type of file. That user the voluntarely wanted to change the default program. In my case, it is an uncontrolled event. Also, just by the registery name, you can see that it concern solely the **current user** not the whole system like in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok So I found the problem...

Yesterday, I have clean out the "installer" folder (which was huge) in Windows using a script I found on the web. The script is supposed to check for dependancies in that folder and let the user delete "unused" files. Big mistake! It seems that some files are still used to link icons.

In conclusion, don't mess up with the "installer" folder AND keep a backup of the files!